# am i doing this right for direct mapping cache

Tags: caching

I wanted your guys opinion on if I'm doing this the right way.

"how much memory is needed for a 128kb (data) cache with 8 byte blocks and 64 bit address line."

Firstly I would put the data cache in power of 2 so that would be 2^17
Then the same with the 8 byte block which would be 2^3

So number of blocks would be 2^17 / 2^3 = 2^14.

Byte offset is always 2 bits.

Index is 14 bits as we got that earlier.

Would the tag be 32-14-2? =>16bits

so cache size is 2^14(64+16+1) = 1296KB?

(1 was gained because of valid bit field)

Comment: Hardware questions are not programming questions.

Comment: Seen quite a lot of direct cache questions here.

Comment: Many wrongs don't make a right.